# how to generate core file in docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, gcc, coredump

using ulimit command, i set core file size.

`ulimit -c unlimited`

and I compiled  c source code using gcc - g option.
then a.out generated.
after command

`./a.out`
there is runtime error .

```
(core dumped)
```

but core file was not generated.(ex. core.294340)

how to generated core file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux

Comment: could it be related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4717#issuecomment-72976973 ?

Answer (score 26):

First make sure the container will write the cores to an existing location in the container filesystem. The core generation settings are set in the host, not in the container. Example:

```
echo '/cores/core.%e.%p' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

will generate cores in the folder /cores.

In your Dockerfile, create that folder:

```
RUN mkdir /cores
```

You need to specify the core size limit; the ulimit shell command would not work, cause it only affects at the current shell. You need to use the docker run option --ulimit with a soft and hard limit. After building the Docker image, run the container with something like:

```
docker run --ulimit core=-1 --mount source=coredumps_volume,target=/cores ab3ca583c907 ./a.out
```

where coredumps_volume is a volume you already created where the core will persist after the container is terminated. E.g.

```
docker volume create coredumps_volume
```

Comment: How to change the path for per container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136601/changing-proc-sys-kernel-core-pattern-file-inside-docker-container

Comment: How can the first command even work in a docker container, `/proc` is mounted as read-only? Basically you should be running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23840737/1804173).

Comment: I could only make it work with `RUN mkdir /cores && chmod 777 /cores` in the Dockerfile (by default it had 755 permission and I was getting no dump file at all). Any idea why write permission to group/other is necessary, considering that my process runs as root?

Answer (score 9):

I keep forgetting how to do it exactly and keep stumbling upon this question which provides marginal help.

All in all it is very simple:

1. Run the container with extra params `--ulimit core=-1  --privileged` to allow coredumps:

```
docker run -it --rm \
--name something \
--ulimit core=-1  --privileged \
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
--entrypoint '/bin/bash' \
$IMAGE
```

2. Then, once in container, set coredump location and start your failing script:

```
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
myfailingscript.a
```

3. Enjoy your stacktrace

```
cd /tmp; gdb -c `ls -t /tmp | grep core | tail -1`
```

Comment: `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern` isn't effective from within the container for me, even with ``--privileged`

Comment: @jberryman not sure, but i think that as long as all three `--ulimit core=-1  --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined` are specified it should work. Unless security options are somehow limited in some other way.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to generate a core dump of an existing process, say using `gcore`, you need to start the container with `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to allow a debugger running as root inside the container to attach to the process. (For core dumps on signals, see the other answer)

Comment: But would it be possible to call `gcore` from the host to avoid giving those rights to the container itself and having to put `gcore` in the image?

Comment: @dolmen Yep, finding the process on the host might be hard, depending on how many containers are running

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's resurrect an ancient thread.

If you're running Docker on Linux, then all of this is controlled by `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` on your raw metal. That is, if you cat that file on bare metal and inside the container, they'll be the same. Note also the file is tricky to update. You have to use the `tee` method from some of the other posts.

```
 echo core | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

If you change it in bare metal, it gets changed in your container. So that also means that behavior is going to be based on where you're running your containers.

My containers don't run apport, but my bare metal did, so I wasn't getting cores. I did the above (I had already solved the ulimit -c thing), and suddenly I get core files in the current directory.

The key to this is understanding that it's your environment, your bare metal, that controls the contents of that file.

Comment: Note that the setting on your bare metal can get reset after a bounce. Apport doesn't like if you do this, after all, and he "knows better". Sigh.