# Changing /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, dockerfile, privileges

How can i change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file inside the docker container with out privileged mode? Are there any flags to be passed to `docker daemon` or `docker run` or anything related to `Dockerfile`?

Comment: lf you get here but are indifferent about the privileged mode, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480387/517914

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kernel does not support per-container patterns. There is a patch for this, but it is unlikely to go in any time soon. The basic problem is that core patterns support piping to a dedicated process which is spawned for this purpose. But the code spawning it does not know how to handle containers just yet. For some reason a simplified pattern handling which requires a target file was not deemed acceptable.

Comment: 3 years later and still I don't see this patch being merged. https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/643798/